# VBS - Counting total files in directory twice

Tags: vbscript, file-rename

Scripters extraordinaire -

I have this script. It does the job it's supposed to do which is pull the first three characters of a file name and move them to the back of the file name. Surely there are parts that could be written better, but I'm just a beginner and this was a way I could get it to work.

What doesn't work about it is the totalFiles count. It ends up going counting the old file as 1 and the new file as 1. So for 50 files in a folder that all get renamed it says 50 of 100.

Suggestions?
Thanks.

```
' Renames MP3s in C:\Directory to move the 3 digit channel number to the end of the filename.
' If the new file name already exists, it is skipped. 
' If the file has already been renamed, it is skipped.



Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\Directory"
Dim sChannel, sRtFile, sNewFile, intCount, totalFiles
intCount = 0
totalFiles =0

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)


Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles
totalFiles = totalFiles + 1
    If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "MP3" Then


        sOldFile = objFSO.GetBaseName(objFile)
        sChannel = Left(sOldFile, Len(sOldFile) - 14)
        sRtFile = Right(sOldFile, Len(sOldFile) - 3)
        sNewFile = sRtFile + sChannel
        'Wscript.Echo sChannel
        If sChannel = "001" Then
            sNewFilePath = objStartFolder + "\" + sNewFile + ".mp3"
            If objFSO.FileExists(sNewFilePath) Then
            Else
            objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Path, sNewFilePath
            intCount = intCount + 1
            End If
        End If
        If sChannel="002" Then
            sNewFilePath = objStartFolder + "\" + sNewFile + ".mp3"
            If objFSO.FileExists(sNewFilePath) Then
            Else
            objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Path, sNewFilePath
            intCount = intCount + 1
            End If
        End If  
        If sChannel="003" Then
            sNewFilePath = objStartFolder + "\" + sNewFile + ".mp3"
            If objFSO.FileExists(sNewFilePath) Then
            Else
            objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Path, sNewFilePath
            intCount = intCount + 1
            End If
        End If
        If sChannel="004" Then
            sNewFilePath = objStartFolder + "\" + sNewFile + ".mp3"
            If objFSO.FileExists(sNewFilePath) Then
            Else
            objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Path, sNewFilePath
            intCount = intCount + 1
            End If
        End If
        If sChannel="005" Then
            sNewFilePath = objStartFolder + "\" + sNewFile + ".mp3"
            If objFSO.FileExists(sNewFilePath) Then
            Else
            objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Path, sNewFilePath
            intCount = intCount + 1
            End If
        End If
        If sChannel="006" Then
            sNewFilePath = objStartFolder + "\" + sNewFile + ".mp3"
            If objFSO.FileExists(sNewFilePath) Then
            Else
            objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Path, sNewFilePath
            intCount = intCount + 1
            End If
        End If
        If sChannel="007" Then
            sNewFilePath = objStartFolder + "\" + sNewFile + ".mp3"
            If objFSO.FileExists(sNewFilePath) Then
            Else
            objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Path, sNewFilePath
            intCount = intCount + 1
            End If
        End If
        If sChannel="008" Then
            sNewFilePath = objStartFolder + "\" + sNewFile + ".mp3"
            If objFSO.FileExists(sNewFilePath) Then
            Else
            objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Path, sNewFilePath
            intCount = intCount + 1
            End If
        End If



    End If

Next


If intCount < totalFiles Then
    Wscript.Echo intCount & " of " & totalFiles & " files renamed." & vbCrLf & "Some files appear to have already been renamed."
Else
    Wscript.Echo intCount & " of " & totalFiles & " files renamed."
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `objFolder.Files.Count` to get the number of files **before** the loop.

**Added:**

To get the number of .MP3 files only, substract the non-.MP3s in the loop from the variable then not named totalFiles but totalMP3s.

Comment: Using Files.Count wouldn't work because I want it to only count the .mp3s. There are other files in the folder. I didn't research Files.Count, so maybe it's capable of counting on a specific file type. At any rate, what I did that works is just another For loop using the same syntax as the main one.

    For Each objFile in colFiles
        If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "MP3" Then
      totalFiles = totalFiles + 1
     End If
    Next

Answer (score -1):

```
'Program to count no of .vbs files in a specified folder

Dim count,looping,extension
count = 0
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder("C:\APRIL\Assignments\Second")
Set totalFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each looping  In totalFiles

extension = objFso.GetExtensionName(looping)
    if(extension = "vbs") Then
    count = count + 1
    End If
Next
MsgBox count
```